# Help needed raising floor in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, subfloor

Help needed raising floor in bathroom

I am renovating my bathroom after a flood (hurricane). I paid a guy to lay my wood floor in the rest of the house. Unfortunately, this raised my floors approximately 1.5” from original. So, I need to raise my bathroom floor to match (or get close enough for a reasonable transition. I’m on a slab.

I’m thinking:

1. Slab
2. Adhesive (Bostik Plus or something similar)
3. 3/4” plywood and taped seams
4. Thinset
5. 1/4” cement board
6. Screws (I haven’t been able to find 3/4” cement board screws… are they out there? I wouldn’t want to punch through the back of the plywood and penetrate the adhesive)
7. Tape seams and screws
8. Redguard
9. Thinset
10. Tiles
11. Grout

I’m concerned about having waterproofing immediately below and immediately above the plywood.

I’m concerned about finding short screws for the cement board.

Am I way off here? What would you do? Importantly, what would you do if the 3/4” plywood was already glued down?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Is the plywood exterior grade? Pressure treated? Is there a vapor barrier under the slab?

Comment: Thank you for your relpy! The ply is pressure treated. I’m not sure about the vapor barrier under the slab. I did make sure to get 100% coverage with the Bostik adhesive that I understand to be waterproof… is that not sufficient?

Comment: Pinching wood between two waterproof barriers is typically considered bad practice. I looked at the TCNA Handbook for interior concrete designs, and there's nothing in there with plywood. I searched Google for `"pressure treated" plywood site:johnbridge.com` and I see lots of nay saying, but no "why" yet.

Comment: From what I can see, the tile setter wisdom against pressure treated wood is based on its high moisture content, where kiln dried after treatment erases their reservations. Since yours is plywood, my expectation is that only its thickness is dimensionally unstable. As long as it's not still sopping wet, I would go for it on my floor. Not on my mom's floor, though.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Truly. A major concern of mine is also not being able to locate concrete board screws short enough. Should I consider a foam backer board like wedi?

Comment: I would substitute stainless screws, https://www.boltdepot.com/Product-Details.aspx?product=3960. There's an ANSI spec,  ANSI A108.11, that requires minimum 1-1/4" length fasteners. That's probably why you can't find any cement board screws to meet your needs.

Comment: After your thinset + backerboard layer, you might let everything dry out for a week or two before waterproofing. If you have time for that, anyway.

Comment: "what would you do if the 3/4” plywood was already glued down?" you're saying you've already glued down the plywood? You may want to make that more explicit in your question...